Not able to use pickle load() with Keras 3
Whenever I run the following code:
file_name = "soil_model_fineTuned.pkl"
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

I get an error like this:
model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src.saving.pickle_utils'

Even though I have installed Keras 3.3.3 and have Tensorflow 2.16.1 with Python 3.10, even if I use joblib, I'm still getting the same error:
model = joblib.load(file_name) 
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1213, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1538, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1580, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src.saving.pickle_utils'

If there is an alternative way to load my pickle model along with Keras 3.3.3 please tell !!
I am expecting for an solution about how to load the pickle model that I have saved but showing different error with keras library, hope i get a good answer.

Try upgrading pip:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Try reinstalling tensorflow:
pip uninstall keras tensorflow -y
pip install tensorflow

Try creating new virtual environment:
python -m venv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate


Hi,
I did those steps.. im using conda on mac and uninstalled and reinstalled both tensorflow and keras but the issue seems to be there.. when i used Keras 2, there was no problem regarding this. :(

Try using virtual environment
'python -m venv myenv'
'source myenv/bin/activate'
